# How to pass parameters from PHP file to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have my file `hotlaps.php` where I have created a script of javascript with:

```
echo "<body onload=\"func1(".$array_1.",".$array_2.",".$array_3.");\">";
```

In my file `hotlaps.js` I have that function:

```
function func1(array1, array2, array3){

    arr1 = array1;
    arr2 = array2;
    arr3 = array3;
    alert(piloto_array[0]);
    start();
}
```

But my variables `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` are undefined. Why?

Comment: So, what do those variables contain? The proper encoding would be → [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) → [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) most likely.

Comment: Need more code to be able to write/help. But essentially you need to use Ajax
http://w3epic.com/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-javascript-javascript-to-php/

Comment: My variables are arrays of values.

Comment: When you view your source, what appears after `<body onload` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body onload='func1(".json_encode($array_1).",".json_encode($array_2).",".json_encode($array_3).");'>";
```

Comment: `json_encode` will use double quotes `"` so you will get nested quoting issues with this.

Comment: So changing " to ' after onload= should help? (i edited post)

Comment: that's a good deal :)

Comment: Thanks you also :D

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make use of your php arrays inside your javascript variables, then you will need to use `json_encode` but be wary that it uses double quotes `"` for arrays, which will break in your example with nested double quotes inside other nested double quotes. use single quotes to avoid that.

I have spaced things out a little better so that you can see what's happening easier.

```
<?php
$array_1 = array ('one','two','three');
$array_2 = array ('four','five','six');
$array_3 = array ('seven','eight','nine');

echo "
  <body onload='
    func1(
      ".json_encode($array_1).",
      ".json_encode($array_2).",
      ".json_encode($array_3)."
    );
  '/>
";

?>

<script>
function func1(array1, array2, array3){
    arr1 = array1;
    arr2 = array2;
    arr3 = array3;
    alert(arr1);
}
</script>
```

Results in this output:

```html
  <body onload='
    func1(
      ["one","two","three"],
      ["four","five","six"],
      ["seven","eight","nine"]
    );
  '/>

<script>
function func1(array1, array2, array3){
    arr1 = array1;
    arr2 = array2;
    arr3 = array3;
    alert(arr1); // just print the first one, you get the idea
}
</script>
```

Comment: You may need to escape the single quotes. After all, this is quite messy. You're better off not using `<body onload />` but e.g. jQuery's `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I agree with not using any of the `on*` [obtrusive javascript attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), but that was per the OP example, as well as the terrible `alert`. As for nested quotes issues, it does depend on the data whether additional escaping is necessary, but double can be guaranteed to break. I have expanded the whitespace on my example to better demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks!!! :DDD It works

Comment: @LigaVirtualF1 glad it works for you :) feel free to accept if it answers the question for you. this will result in +2 rep for you. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/321521)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the syntax and avoid the mess with the quotes (IMHO) you could initialize the variables in PHP and JS like that:

```
<?php
$array_1 = json_encode([1,2,3]);
$array_2 = json_encode([4,5,6]);
$array_3 = json_encode([7,8,9]);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array_1 = <?php echo $array_1; ?>,
        array_2 = <?php echo $array_2; ?>,
        array_3 = <?php echo $array_3; ?>;
</script>
<body onload="func1(array_1,array_2,array_3)">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func1(array1, array2, array3) {
        console.log(array1);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to print the variables from php into your html code

```
<body onload=\"func1("<?php echo $array_1; ?>","<?php echo $array_2; ?>","<?php echo $array_3; ?>");\">";
```

Comment: `Notice: Array to string conversion`